# c++ to delphi convert

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

Now I'm trying to get the picture from my Dahua Terminal, and the code becomes a little trick.

In C++ sample code, I have:

```cpp
//Struct

// face info
typedef struct tagNET_ACCESS_FACE_INFO
{
    char                        szUserID[32];                                       // user ID
    int                         nFaceData;                                          // count of face data,the max number is 20
    char                        szFaceData[20][2048];                               // face data
    int                         nFaceDataLen[20];                                   // face data length
    int                         nFacePhoto;                                         // count of face photo,max size: 5
    int                         nInFacePhotoLen[5];                                 // the size of each photo used by the user
    int                         nOutFacePhotoLen[5];                                // the actual size of each photo
    char*                       pFacePhoto[5];                                      // face photo data,max size: 120K
    BYTE                        byReserved[2048];                                   // reserved
} NET_ACCESS_FACE_INFO;


//Part of the c++ code
//...


    NET_ACCESS_FACE_INFO stuFaceInfo;
    memset(&stuFaceInfo,0,sizeof(stuFaceInfo));
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        stuFaceInfo.nInFacePhotoLen[i] = 100*1024;
        stuFaceInfo.pFacePhoto[i] = new char[100*1024]; //<-- Don´t know how do it
        memset(stuFaceInfo.pFacePhoto[i],0,100*1024);
    }
    stuFaceGetOut.pFaceInfo = &stuFaceInfo;
```

I convert to this Delphi code:

```pascal
// face info Record
  PNetAccessFaceInfo = ^TNetAccessFaceInfo;
  TNetAccessFaceInfo = record
    szUserID: array[0..31] of AnsiChar;              // user ID
    nFaceData: Integer;                              // count of face data,the max number is 20
    szFaceData: array[0..19, 0..2047] of AnsiChar;   // face data
    nFaceDataLen: array[0..19] of Integer;           // face data length
    nFacePhoto: Integer;                             // count of face photo,max size: 5
    nInFacePhotoLen: array[0..4] of Integer;         // the size of each photo used by the user
    nOutFacePhotoLen: array[0..4] of Integer;        // the actual size of each photo
    pFacePhoto: array[0..4] of PAnsiChar;            // face photo data,max size: 120K
    byReserved: array[0..2047] of Byte;             // reserved
  end;

...
var
  faceInfo: TNetAccessFaceInfo;
begin
  ...
  ZeroMemory(@faceInfo,sizeOf(faceInfo));
  for I := 0 to 4 do
    begin
      faceInfo.nInFacePhotoLen[i] := 100*1024;
      ZeroMemory(@faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i],sizeof(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i])); //<-- this get nothing, no error code, no crash
//      faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i] := pAnsichar(100*1024); //<-- tryed this but got a exception
      FillChar(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i],0,100*1024);
    end;
```

With `pFacePhoto *char[5]` I convert to `pFacePhoto : Array [0..4] of PAnsiChar;`

But in the sample code, `...pfacePhoto[i] = new char[100*1024]` in my limited knowledge of C++ means the `PAnsiChar` receiving a Delphi array `[0..(100*1024)-1] of AnsiChar`.

Since `pFacePhoto[i]` is a `PAnsiChar`, can I create a new array of `AnsiChar` and point to it?

Running my Delphi code, I get this from `GetLastError()`:

```cpp
#define NET_RETURN_DATA_ERROR                   _EC(21)     // Error occurs when verify returned data.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the sample code, `...pfacePhoto[i] = new char[100*1024]` in my limited knowledge of C++ means the `PAnsiChar` receiving a Delphi array `[0..(100*1024)-1] of AnsiChar`.
>
> Since `pFacePhoto[i]` is a `PAnsiChar`, can I create a new array of AnsiChar and point to it?

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.  You need to allocate an array of `100*1024` number of `AnsiChar` elements, and then point `pFacePhoto[i]` to the 1st element of that array.

There are different ways you can do that, for instance by using [`GetMem()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.GetMem):

```pascal
var
  faceInfo: TNetAccessFaceInfo;
begin
  ...
  ZeroMemory(@faceInfo, SizeOf(faceInfo));
  for I := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    faceInfo.nInFacePhotoLen[i] := 100*1024;
    GetMem(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i], 100*1024);
    ZeroMemory(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i], 100*1024);
  end;
  ...
  for I := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    FreeMem(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i]);
  end;
```

Or, using [`AnsiStrings.AnsiStrAlloc()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiStrings.AnsiStrAlloc):

```pascal
uses
  ..., AnsiStrings;

var
  faceInfo: TNetAccessFaceInfo;
begin
  ...
  ZeroMemory(@faceInfo, SizeOf(faceInfo));
  for I := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    faceInfo.nInFacePhotoLen[i] := 100*1024;
    faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i] := AnsiStrAlloc(100*1024);
    ZeroMemory(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i], 100*1024);
  end;
  ...
  for I := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    StrDispose(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i]);
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, can you help me to undertand this code ? `m_modifyPic.SetImageDate((BYTE*)stuFaceInfo.pFacePhoto[0], stuFaceInfo.nOutFacePhotoLen[0]);`

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it? `pFacePhoto[0]` is a `char*` that is pointing at some buffer which is `nOutFacePhotoLen[0]` bytes in size. The code is passing that buffer to `SetImageDate()`, and presumably `SetImageDate()` expects a pointer to a `BYTE[]` buffer not a `char[]` buffer, so the code is merely type-casting from `char*` to `BYTE*`

Comment: That part i undertand, what i have stuck is convert this to delphi. `          Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
          Try
            for I := 0 to 4 do
              mlog.Lines.Add(faceinfo.pfacePhoto[i]); //<- to check raw data
            ms.Write(faceinfo.pFacePhoto[0],faceinfo.nOutFacePhotoLen[0]); //<-- trying to read the info to memorystream
            imgFoto.Picture.LoadFromStream(ms);
          Finally
            for i := 0 to 4 do
              StrDispose(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i]); //<<-- releasing memory
            FreeAndNil(ms);
          End;`

Comment: After calling `ms.Write()`, the stream's `Position` is at the *end* of the stream. You need to seek the `Position` back to 0 *before* calling `Picture.LoadFromStream()`, otherwise there is nothing for it to load. Also, you can't "check raw data" using `mlog.Lines.Add(faceinfo.pfacePhoto[i])` since the data is not textual to begin with.

Comment: The pfacePhoto[0] only receives ` ÿØÿà `, if i´m not wrong, this is the header fo the jpg descriptor, but nothing else comes. Can be something in this ? `faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i] := AnsiStrAlloc(100*1024);`

Comment: iei \o/ . It Works. Cast to TBytes, `   if Ret then
    begin
      Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      Try
        ms.Write(TBytes(faceinfo.pFacePhoto[0]),faceinfo.nOutFacePhotoLen[0]);
        ms.position := 0;
        imgFoto.Picture.LoadFromStream(ms);
      Finally
        for i := 0 to 4 do
          FreeMem(faceInfo.pFacePhoto[i]);
        FreeAndNil(ms);
      End;
    end `

Comment: As I said earlier: "*the data is not textual to begin with*". So, you can't display the data as-is as plain text, you have to *encode* it into a human-readable form, like hex. Also, `TBytes` is a dynamic array, which has metadata inside of it, which your data does not have, so a simple type-cast to `TBytes` is wrong. There was nothing wrong with your original `Write()`, all you were missing was the `Position` reset: `ms := TMemoryStream.Create; try ms.Write(faceinfo.pFacePhoto[0], faceinfo.nOutFacePhotoLen[0]); ms.Position := 0; imgFoto.Picture.LoadFromStream(ms); finally ms.Free; end;`

Comment: Withiout type-cast to Tbytes i got a "Unsupported stream format", With TBytes cast works. something about nFacePhoto is a array of PAnsiChar and needed to be casted to ?

Comment: You CAN'T type-cast a raw `PAnsiChar` to a `TBytes` like this, because it is simply NOT a valid [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) pointer. The type-cast has NOTHING to do with the format of the image data. The reason the load fails without the cast is because you are not writing the data into the `TMemoryStream` correctly. You need to use this instead: `ms.Write(faceinfo.pFacePhoto[0]^, faceinfo.nOutFacePhotoLen[0]);` instead. Note the extra `^` dereference ...

Comment: ... the 1st parameter of `Write()` is an **untyped** `const` param, so it receives a *reference* to whatever is passed to it. By passing just `pFacePhoto[0]`, `Write()` will receive a reference to `pFacePhoto[0]` itself, not a reference to the memory that `pFacePhoto[0]` points at.  So you have to dereference the pointer in `pFacePhoto[0]` so that `Write()` will receive a reference to the char data instead.

Comment: You are awesome, :DDDDD.  now its running without typecast and with ^ at the end. thnks again